# Exponential Distribution. Struggling with real life application below

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution

The amount of sugar needed in one day in a sugar refinery has an exponential distribution with mean 4 tons. How much sugar should be stocked each day to ensure the chance of running out is only 0.05?

I am struggling to identify the definition for the random variable in this situation and how I would find this

I have a very low level of stats, not a stats student.

Comment: They give you the rate parameter.  All you have to do is compute the probability in the right tail.  This problem should get the self-study tag.

Comment: dude help a brother out I've spent 2 hours on it

Comment: is my random variable x = the amount of sugar used

Comment: Yes that is correct.  This question does require the self-study tag. I can give hints only.  I will give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since the mean is 4 the rate parameter lambda is 1/4.  The integral of $\lambda$exp(-$\lambda$x) from 0 to y is 0.95.  So solve for y. That will be the correct amount.

Comment: I get to a point with a negative exponential to the power of y/4 minus 1 being equal to 0.95. I can't apply a log to a negative exponential at least I don't know how to

Comment: It is 1-exp(-y/4)=0.95 or exp(-y/4)=0.05.  Then you should be able to solve for y by taking logs and doing a little algebra.

Comment: -exp(-y/4)-1=0.95 is what i got which becomes exp(-y/4)=0.05

Comment: Sorry I corrected my answer.  It is exp(-x/4)/4 that is the density and if you integrate it from 0 to y you get 1-exp(-y/4)=0.95.  So exp(-y/4)=.05 or -y/4 = ln(0.05)

Comment: "exp(-x/4)/4" why is this over 4

Comment: sorry ignore that i understand why

Comment: Good so my answer helped. You can give me an upvote and check the answer if it got you to the correct solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help I got an answer of 11.98 so 12 tons of sugar should. I'll give you an up vote

Comment: Great Now you know how to do this type of problem.

Comment: Peace and one love brethren